# IOS : wrong Czech country code

Tags: ios, country-codes

I think I found a bug in iOS Czech contacts. I've created a Czech contact (With *Czech Republic* country) that i selected in my application with a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

The log of address that ABPeoplePickerNavigationController returned me is:

```
"Country" : "Czech Republic"
"Street" : "A street"
"CountryCode" : "cs"
"City" : "A city"
"ZIP" : "12345"
```

So the country code is CS. But when I attempt to retreive the corresponding name,

```
NSString *countryCode = [address objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey];
if (countryCode != nil) {
    NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
    name = [[applicationDelegate dataManager] objectForEntityForName:@"Name" withValue:countryName forKey:@"name"];
}
```

`name` gives me : "Serbia and Montenegro" !

According to http://countrycode.org/, the Czech country code is CK, and according to http://xml.coverpages.org/country3166.html, CS is for Czechoslovakia, but "no longer exists"

How would I tell this at Apple ?

Comment: I didn't entered CS neither CZ, I've just created my contact, selected "Czech Republic" as country, saved, and accessed him from ABPeoplePickerNavController.  But I didn't try to manualy set CZ. I'm pretty sure it would work...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up country codes (ISO 3166-X) and language codes (ISO 639-X).
The language code for Czech language according to ISO 639-1 is "CS".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes

Note:
A long time ago this also used to be the country code for former "Czechoslovakia" in ISO 3166-1, but it has been changed and reassigned (e.g. to Serbia and Montenegro, which now is "YU") several times due to political changes.